# How to set vlookup match formula without spliting?

Tags: excel

Raw Data:

[image: Raw Data]

Need:

[image: Need]

I need ID (in need table) based on Alphabet (from Raw data) without splitting cell.

Comment: You desired output makes no sense if we look and compare it to the raw data. Also, please include your own attempt. See [ask] a question with an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming raw data is in A2:B5, and a,b,c etc in D2, D3 etc.

=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH("*"&D2&"*",$B$2:$B$5,0))

Comment: Please check again & reply based on cell number

Comment: Check what exactly?

Comment: pictures have Column & Row number, set formula based on pictures Column & Row number

Comment: I've changed it to refer to column D instead of E for a,b,c,d etc.